# Jersey 1.8 (Custom) Logging filter

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, logging, jersey

web.xml had

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
  <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
  <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
```

This does not print the incoming request entity. It only prints headers and other stuff. Request entity prints as empty string

Then I took a reference code from LoggingFilter to see why it isn't working

```
    final StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    printRequestLine(b, request);
    printRequestHeaders(b, request.getRequestHeaders());


    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    InputStream in = request.getEntityInputStream();
    try {
        if(in.available() > 0) {
            ReaderWriter.writeTo(in, out);

            byte[] requestEntity = out.toByteArray();
            printEntity(b, requestEntity);

            request.setEntityInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(requestEntity));
        }
        return request;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new ContainerException(ex);
    } finally {
        logger.info(b.toString());
    }
```

InputStream is holding object of

```
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream
```

If I remove the condition if(in.available() > 0) this code works and prints the request

in.available() always returns 0 where as the input stream is holding the incoming request

What might be the case the code will fail if I remove that condition?
And what is the reason it is not giving me available() value?

Comment: [Seems related to Tomcat](https://java.net/jira/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/JERSEY-749/JERSEY-749.html). There's a comment somewhere there that suggests using the NIO connector.

Answer (score 0):

The logging filter does not print entities by default. There is a constructor to enable it.

https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.11/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/filter/LoggingFilter.html#LoggingFilter(java.util.logging.Logger, boolean)